# Why Google Chrome can not Update it-self?

Tags: google-chrome, updates

Google chrome (that I downloaded from FileHipoo.com) can not update it-self?

The error message is

`Update failed (error: 3)An error occurred while checking for updates: Update check failed to start (error code 3: 0x80040154).`

I just want to understand the reason.

Comment: Why didn't you [download it direct](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/)? You have chosen to download it, for unknown reasons, from a third party... therefore you could, in theory, of downloaded and installed anything, something claiming to be what you think... You may have a different version, an old version, a faulty version etc

Comment: It looks like 0x80040154 is [class not registered](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/201191), which would point toward an incomplete installation for some reason. While that MSKB article isn't directly applicable to your situation, I would expect the error code to not have some other additional meaning. @DaveRook

Comment: @DaveRook : Because I Can not download it directly for several reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is quite clear in that it fails to start, but as to why... I don't know for sure. It would APPEAR that earlier versions installed Chrome to your `%localAppData%` directory - it now installs to `%ProgramFiles%` which fixes this error for many users. I can only therefore guess that due to downloading from a third party source to the vendor you've got an older version.

[Download the latest version of Chrome from Google](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/index.html?system=true#eula) (but un-install your version first, saving/backing up bookmarks/plug ins etc first)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. After updating Chrome x64, I decided to update Chrome Canary x64 too. Since the auto-update from the About page failed, I ran the new installer manually and it succeeded. On the About page I saw I have the new version, but it still showed the same error. Then I noticed that 3-4 processes from Google update service are running as a Scheduled Task. I tried to stop the task, but this had no effect.

**This solved my issue:**
Finally I used End process tree from Process Explorer. Now the About page is showing: Google Chrome is up to date. :)